# Get Image Url from column "EncodedAbsUrl" using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, csom

Currently creating a SharePoint hosted APP.

I am trying to get image URL from Picture Library (Collection) with Column internal name `EncodedAbsUrl` using CSOM ,
I have picture lib Collection but not yet succeed,

```
    var libraryName ="Image Slider";
    var camlQuery=new SP.CamlQuery();
   camlQuery.set_viewXml="<view><Query><Where><IsNotNull><FieldRefName='EncodedAbsUrl' /></IsNotNull></Where><Query></view>";
    libraryItems = library.getItems(camlQuery);
    var listEnumerator = libraryItems.getEnumerator();
    var currentItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
   //here Not getting **EncodedAbsUrl** column value

        var imagePath=currentItem.get_item("EncodedAbsUrl"); 
        var link=currentItem.get_item("URL");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the items and then call `executequeryasync`. Something like:

```
clientContext.load(libraryItems, 'Include(EncodedAbsUrl,URL)');
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

Then in the success method, you can get the field values. Check this for more information on how to get list items using JavaScript client object model:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: I had done same like u said , m getting all values like ID, Title etc but not Getting Image  URL

Comment: make sure that you are using the correct field name. Note that you need to use the internal field name

Comment: Nadeem , Now Its Working for Me,  can u please explain why need to use Include(EncodedAbsUrl,URL)

Comment: Now i'm Able to get "EncodedAbsUrl" but not custom column "URL" value

Comment: wishing I could get EncodedAbsUrl for the .NET managed CSOM